# PostgreSql. Чем User отличается от Group Role?

Tags: postgresql, sql

PostgreSql. Чем User отличается от Group Role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Группа (group role) — это просто группа из нескольких пользователей (user/login role).

Чтобы если Васе, Пете и Маше надо обеспечить права на такие-то объекты, чтобы не прописывать по три записи (а потом, когда появится Коля, оббегать всю БД), а запихать их в группу и выдать права на нее.